# Google Cloud and Firebase Browser vs Server key

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

So I am fairly new to firebase and new to the more advanced concepts of gcloud and i'm setting up firebase with hosting and analytics and in the gcloud console it generated a Server key and a Browser key however they look like identical keys, both unrestricted, and when i copied the code for the fire base analytics google sent me an email warning me about the api key being public (public github repo) is it safe to publish the unrestricted browser key, if so why? If someone could explain how api keys work within google cloud that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Cloud Platform has a number of API keys. These are generated for Android, iOS and web (Browser) applications and there is also a Server API key. Anyone with an API key can call the REST APIs on resources on the project it was generated for. This can incur major billing charges!

It is advisable to restrict API keys. Only give them access to the APIs they need to use. Android and iOS keys should be restricted to the applications the project support.

The browser key is the one to be careful with as the key is stored in a JavaScript object and easily obtainable. It should be restricted to the domain the web pages are served from. If email address and password authentication is enabled, an unrestricted API key can be used to create and modify users.

So no, it is not safe to publish an unrestricted browser API key.